# When is it useful to use `ref` with a function paramter

Tags: rust, binding

This question is *not* about the difference between `fn foo(x: &T)` and `fn foo(ref x: T)`.

I wish to ask when it's desirable / idiomatically correct to use the latter. I'm unable to imagine a scenario you would need the `ref` keyword in a function signature because you could just declare `fn foo(x: T)` and use `&x` inside the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the top level of a function parameter list, there is no reasonable use case for `ref`. It basically results in ownership of the value being moved into the function, but you only get a reference to work with.

The reason this is allowed in a function parameter list is consistency with the pattern matching syntax in other parts of the language. You can use any irrefutable pattern as a function parameter, just like in `let` statements. Syntax and semantics of these assignments are essentially the same, but not everything that's technically *allowed* to be in a function parameter list actually makes sense there, just as not all code that compiles is actually useful. Clippy [warns against using `ref` at the top level of a function parameter list](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#toplevel_ref_arg).

It *may* be useful to use `ref` in destructuring in a function parameter list. If you accept, say, a reference to a pair `&(String, String)`, and you want to give individual names to the to the two entries, you can use

```
fn foo(&(ref x, ref y): &(String, String))
```

to achieve this. Not using `ref` here would be invalid, since you can't take ownership of these strings.

Since the arrival of [match ergonomics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2005-match-ergonomics.md), this (and most other) uses of the `ref` keyword can be rewritten using the more succinct syntax

```
fn foo((x, y): &(String, String))
```

I personally prefer the longer, more explicit version, since the "ergonomic" version makes the types that `x` and `y` have more opaque.

Comment: Yes agreed about the longer, more explicit version being preferable in this case.